# Pass the function as an argument in jest test

Tags: jestjs

I want to test this function

```
export const compare = selector => (a, b) => selector(a).localeCompare(selector(b))
```

Currently, the compare function is being called as

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        items: getPolicies(state)
        .map(d => d)
        .sort(compare(d => d.name)),
 })
```

My jest unit looks like this:

```
import each from 'jest-each'
import { compare } from './sorting'

describe('sorting functions test', () => {
  describe('compare tests', () => {
    const func = jest.fn(value => value.name)
    each([{ name: 'hello' }, { name: 'world' }], func)
    it('return -1', () => {
      expect(compare(func)).toBe(-1)
    })
  })
})
```

I just do not see/ find way to pass/mock the d => d.name for the argument.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve it

```
import { compare } from './sorting'

describe('sorting functions test', () => {
  describe('compare function tests', () => {
    it('returns -1', () => {
      const selector = jest.fn(value => value.name)
      const compareFunc = compare(selector)
      expect(compareFunc({ name: 'hello' }, { name: 'world' })).toBe(-1)
      expect(selector).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(selector).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3)
    })
  })
})
```

[Guidance found here](https://alligator.io/testing/mock-functions/)